# Function or Macro to Apply Other Functions Determined by Keywords

Tags: function, common-lisp, symbols, keyword, dispatch

I would like to be able to write a function like:

```
(dispatchme :foo)
```

which then executes:

```
(foo!)
```

in which the colon of the colon has been stripped off the keyword and (in this case) and exclamation point has been added to determine the final function name.  `foo!` is defined separately and I want to avoid using some kind of dispatch table such as using `cond` or a `hash-table` - there could be a number of keyword/function pairs in principle.

Comment: I have just made another attempt at writing a macro (having had a new idea!)  ```(defun foo! () (print "It Worked!"))``` and then ```(defmacro dispatchme (keyword) (let ((func-name (intern (format nil "~A!" keyword)))) `(,func-name)))``` worked ok for ```(dispatchme :foo)```.  However, as this function will be called a large number of times, I am wondering whether I can speed things up slightly in the place where I generate ```func-name``` using ```intern``` and ```format```.  If anyone has suggestions I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that the conventions you imply are observed, you can simply do that, but you need to think about the package.  I'll assume that you have that in a special variable, but maybe you want `*package*` (i. e. the current package at run time) or `#.*package*` (i. e. the current package at read time) there:

```
(defun call-by-key (keyword)
  (funcall (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name keyword) "!")
                   *special-package*)))
```

However, the only sensible use case I have seen for such things is when the required packages have not been created yet at the time when the function call is read, i. e. in a system definition (ASDF).  So, the question for me would be: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for this feedback.  This particular code is in very early days and I am using CL-USER to avoid having to type in package names.  I had first developed my code using Generic Functions and Classes as I typically do but it turned out to be slow for large inputs so I am experimenting with using HASH-TABLES, ARRAYS and STRUCTS.  Since this is entirely exploratory just now it's tough for me to be more precise at this point.  My initial attempts used APPLY but that was slow and using a MACRO in one case was faster.  I will come back and clarify when able.  Thanks again.